# How to use a trained TensorFlow model inside a custom loss function in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

## Problem Statement

I want to use a pretrained TensorFlow model inside a custom loss function to train another model, but get an error message. I am using TensorFlow 2.3 Keras with this code, where the pretrained model named 'discriminator_model' is handed over to the custom_loss:

## Code snippet

```
def custom_loss(discriminator_model):

    def loss_function(y_actual, y_pred):
        prediction_actual = discriminator_model.predict(y_actual)
        prediction_pred = discriminator_model.predict(y_pred)
        custom_loss = (prediction_pred - prediction_actual)**2
        return custom_loss

    return loss_function

...

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr_schedule), loss=custom_loss(discriminator_model), metrics='mse')
    generator_model.fit(DG_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
```

## Error message

```
RuntimeError: Detected a call to `Model.predict` inside a `tf.function`. `Model.predict is a high-level endpoint that manages its own `tf.function`. Please move the call to `Model.predict` outside of all enclosing `tf.function`s. Note that you can call a `Model` directly on `Tensor`s inside a `tf.function` like: `model(x)`.
```

Is there a way to use a pretrained model inside a custom loss function? I think there should be, as this is also the underlying idea behind GANs, right? But how?

Comment: The error says to not use `model.predict`, so why don't you try just calling the model? `discriminator_model(y_actual)`. But, it seems like you're calling your model on the targets?

Comment: @NicolasGervais: Thank you for the hint, it works now with: ´prediction_actual = discriminator_model(y_actual)´!